# How to detect Ethereum ERC721 token

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I have read the [EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/165) abount ERC165 that is enable us to detect which interface is implemented in a contract.

However, I found that some ERC721 tokens are a little bit diffrent from others, like [cryptokitties](https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d) and [cryptohorse](http://www.cryptohorse.ch/sourceC.html).

Are these different ERC721 tokens are both detected as erc721 token by wallet application.

And how does erc721 support wallet detect the type of tokens.

Answer (score 4):

ERC-721 is a standard, [published in](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) the Ethereum EIPs project.

Cryptokitties, cryptohorse, cryptotitties, etc. all went live BEFORE the standard. Therefore they are not ERC-721. Many people will refer to them as 721, but they are actually not 721.

Any wallet that wants to work with these pre-standard applications will need to manually add support, one-off, for each one. Going forward these wallets will probably only support Cryptokitties, a couple others, and then all actually compliant ERC-721 contracts.